# Visual Studio 2015 Extensions for Code block

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I have installed some extensions in VS 2013 couple years ago and got the options in IDE. I was trying to get the similar extensions in VS2015 and somehow I'm not finding which extension provided these ones...

[Visual Studio 2015 - code block ending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPHVD.png) -> if the code block moved up in the screen, you may not be seeing the start of the code block, so this extension shows the starting line of the block at the bottom on the block.

[Visual Studio 2015 - Locate TFS/Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5pYe.png) -> when right clicking on the file, you would see Locate TFS, Locate in Solution Explorer options, so you can directly go to either the TFS location or the Solution Explorer.

Can someone share what are those extension names for VS2015 for the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Visual Studio 2015 - code block ending:**

You could install [CodeBlockEndTag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KhaosPrinz.CodeBlockEndTag#overview) extension in Visual Studio 2015

**Visual Studio 2015 - Locate TFS/Solution Explorer:**

You need to install two extensions, [Find in Solution Explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SamHarwell.FindinSolutionExplorer) and [Locate in TFS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AlexPendleton.LocateinTFS#overview), to implement your requirement.

And you also check the extension Name in your Visual Studio 2013 and then search them from [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?target=VS&category=Tools&vsVersion=&subCategory=All&sortBy=Downloads) to check whether they are support for Visual Studio 2015.